# Is this stack frame drawn properly?

Tags: c, stack

[image]

I have being trying to work on stack frames, and drawing their representation. Is what I have written accurate for the factorial of 3?

Comment: Conceptually? Yes it seems correct. I must say however, that this question seems ill-fitted for SO however.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I certainly apologize. I will delete it if you would like?

Comment: I'm not too disturbed about the question remaining. It's just that for a Q&A format, "Is what I have written correct" sounds to me a bit Off-Topic. I'm not sure *it is* off topic on SO, or I would have down-voted. It's also not badly written or specified, or I would have down voted just the same. So you should leave it, it's just seems off to me.